# 2 threads left hanging waiting on QWaitCondition in spite of wakeAll calls

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, vtk

I have threaded iterative generation of some geometries. I use VTK for rendering. After each iteration I would like to display (render) the current progress. My approach works as expected until the last 2 threads are left hanging waiting for QWaitCondition. They are blocked, even though their status in QWaitCondition's queue is wokenUp (inspected through debugger). I suspect that number of 2 threads is somehow connected with my processor's 4 cores.

Simplified code is below. What am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

```
class Logic
{
    QMutex threadLock, renderLock;
    //SOLUTION: renderLock should be per thread, not global like this!
    QWaitCondition wc;
    bool render;
    ...
}

Logic::Logic()
{
    ...
    renderLock.lock(); //needs to be locked for QWaitCondition
}

void Logic::timerProc()
{
    static int count=0;
    if (render||count>10) //render wanted or not rendered in a while
    {
        threadLock.lock();
        vtkRenderWindow->Render();
        render=false;
        count=0;
        wc.wakeAll();
        threadLock.unlock();
    }
    else
        count++;
}

double Logic::makeMesh(int meshIndex)
{
    while (notFinished)
    {
        ...(calculate g)
        threadLock.lock(); //lock scene
        mesh[meshIndex]->setGeometry(g);
        render=true;
        threadLock.unlock();
        wc.wait(&renderLock); //wait until rendered
    }
    return g.size;
}

void Logic::makeAllMeshes()
{
    vector<QFuture<double>> r;
    for (int i=0; i<meshes.size(); i++)
    {       
        QFuture<double> future = QtConcurrent::run<double>(this, &Logic::makeMesh, i);
        r.push_back(future);
    }

    while(any r is not finished)
        QApplication::processEvents(); //give timer a chance
}
```

Comment: You must call wait on locked mutex!

Comment: I do: wc.wait(&renderLock); Or is some additional call required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The catch was that I needed one QMutex per thread, and not just one global QMutex. The corrected code is below. Thanks for help UmNyobe!

```
class Logic
{
    QMutex threadLock;
    QWaitCondition wc;
    bool render;
    ...
}

//nothing in constructor related to threading

void Logic::timerProc()
{
    //count was a debugging workaround and is not needed
    if (render)
    {
        threadLock.lock();
        vtkRenderWindow->Render();
        render=false;
        wc.wakeAll();
        threadLock.unlock();
    }
}

double Logic::makeMesh(int meshIndex)
{
    QMutex renderLock; //fix
    renderLock.lock(); //fix
    while (notFinished)
    {
        ...(calculate g)
        threadLock.lock(); //lock scene
        mesh[meshIndex]->setGeometry(g);
        render=true;
        threadLock.unlock();
        wc.wait(&renderLock); //wait until rendered
    }
    return g.size;
}

void Logic::makeAllMeshes()
{
    vector<QFuture<double>> r;
    for (int i=0; i<meshes.size(); i++)
    {       
        QFuture<double> future = QtConcurrent::run<double>(this, &Logic::makeMesh, i);
        r.push_back(future);
    }

    while(any r is not finished)
        QApplication::processEvents(); //give timer a chance
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is at least one defect in your code. `count` and `render` belong to the critical section, which means they need to be protected from concurrent access.

Assume there are more threads waiting on `wc.wait(&renderLock);`. Someone somewhere execute `wc.wakeAll();`. ALL the threads are woken up. Assume at least one thread sees `notFinished` as true (if any of your code make sense, this ***must*** be possible) and go back to execute :

```
    threadLock.lock(); //lock scene
    mesh[meshIndex]->setGeometry(g);
    render=true;
    threadLock.unlock();
    wc.wait(&renderLock) <----OOPS...
```

The second time the thread comes back, he doesn't have the lock `renderLock`. So  **Kamil Klimek** is right: **you call wait on a mutex you don't hold**.

You should remove the lock in constructor, and lock before the calling the condition. Wherever you lock `renderlock`, the thread should not hold `threadlock`.

Comment: count was a workaround attempt to unlock the threads, and it is not accessed concurrently - only the main thread ever accesses it.
But I did as you suggested and it makes no difference.

Comment: from your post it is confusing which operations the thread can do in parallel. Is it `...calculate g`? so why is it in a loop? Where does the variable `notFinished` set?